# Tinymce New Line and Escaping error

Tags: php, html, css, escaping, tinymce

I have a online webpage editor in which i have used Tinymce.

I am having extreme problem as when i press enter key , instead of `<br>`, it inserts `/r/n` special characters.

Moreover whenever I insert a link or Image Path or even the Height or Width of an object, it displays as follows:

Link: `<a href="\"../page/swami-sant-dass-ji\"">Read More</a>`

Image: `<img src="\"../n/assets/images/swamiji.jpg\"">`

this is messing up with my website. Moreover, `stripslashes` function is not solving the problem, it does not have any affect

Help Appreciated!

**EDIT**

My Tinymce Initializer is:

```
tinymce.init({ 
            selector:'textarea#texteditor1',
            height: 500,
            theme: 'modern',
            force_br_newlines : true,
            force_p_newlines : false,
            forced_root_block : '',
            plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
            'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
            ],
            toolbar1: 'code | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image codesample | preview',
            image_advtab: true,
            table_default_attributes: {
                class: 'table table-bordered table-striped',
                id:'datatable-table-page'
            },
            entity_encoding: "raw",
            content_css: [
            '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
            '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was sanitizing the tinymce input when processing the submission with PHP, specifically with `mysqli_real_escape_string`. This added escapes to everything that could be read by HTML, SQL, whatever.

So like @Michael Fromin said, if it's displaying correctly in the editor but displays badly wherever it posts to, it's getting changed somewhere in the submission script where it takes and posts the editor input.

Answer (score 0):

If I take your TinyMCE configuration and load it in TinyMCE Fiddle inserting a link or image does not create the strange results you reference.

If (before you save/reload the content) things look correct in TinyMCE but they get messed up upon reload this is an issue in your application's code and not TinyMCE.